# Android Navigation Drawer Error ActionBarDrawerToggle Not Woking

Tags: android, navigation-drawer

[image: What's the Problem With this line? I am not able to fix the error]

What's the Problem With this line? I am not able to fix the error

Comment: hover over line and check what's the problem or click on the line and press alt+enter

Answer (score 0, accepted):

because you imported support.V7 ActionBarDrawerToggle check below you will get an idea

```
android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle toggle2 = new android.support.v4.app.ActionBarDrawerToggle( this, drawer, R.drawable.download, R.string.navigation_drawer_open, R.string.navigation_drawer_close);
```

but this on is deprecated
for more info check https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v4/app/ActionBarDrawerToggle.html